# The best way to use three-valued logic variables

Tags: java

I'm looking for the best way to implement  three-valued logic.

I googled and found three different approaches:

1. Use `null` value for `Boolean` variable as undefined

   This variant looks to dangerous for me because it can unexpectedly cause `NullPointerException`
2. Use `Optional<Boolean>` type

   This variant still is a bit dangerous. To avoid `NoSuchElementException` you should use constructions like this:

   ```
   Optional<Boolean> amIRight = Optional.empty();
   if (Optional.of(true).equals(amIRight ) {
       doSome();
   }
   ```

   It looks too wordy for me
3. Implement your own enum

   The last variant seems to be the best. Almost safe, very simple in undefstanding. But I haven't find any of such enums in widely spread java libriaries such as Apache, Google Guava and so on. It looks strange for me everybody avoids the simpler and safest implementation.

   May be I missed something and there are serious reason not to implement three-valued logic enum.

Comment: Go with the enum.

Comment: 1. enums can still be `null`, so it isn't that different from just using `Boolean`, 2. for `Optional` the use of `someOptional.orElse(false)` is shorter and easier to read than your current 'solution'.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Null isn't the point. The point is that booleans aren't supposed to be [tri-state](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes it can, but i hardly can image enybody who would do so. Also i hardly can imagine enybody who would expect that some method could return null as a Boolean result.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel your someOptional.orElse(false) is not what i desire because i need a solution which would help me to compare values. I need to know if the value is exactly true or false.

Comment: The example piece of code shown does exactly the same. Maybe you need to better illustrate the problem you are trying to solve. As it stands it looks like you have already chosen the enum solution and you just want a bit of confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

If enum works for you, go for it.
Don't use that Boolean, it is ugly and destroy readability ... I also can't imagine how horrible it would be if you want it to support 4 values later...

**Other cautions / advise :**

Are you sure that you will use only 3 values?
   In many situation, design tends to change, and enum will be no longer enough.
Using a class that encapsulate enum (or int) can provide better flexibility.
However, you can change from enum to class later.

In my program, I extensively use enum.
You shouldn't care much about what popular libraries do, just pick the best that work for you!

**About the very interesting hypothesis :**

> ... there are serious reason not to implement three-valued logic enum. ...

Suppose that I am Java language designer.
You ask for a `3-logic enum`.
I accept you proposal.

Then, `Mr.2D` ask "We have `3-logic enum`. Why don't you provide `4-logic enum` to support `+x -x +y -y`?".
I give him what he want.

After that, `Mr.LoveFive` `Mr.ObsessiveSick` ..... I think you got the point.

There has to be a threshold (when to stop) and the demand for 3-enum is relatively very low compared to 2-enum (boolean).

Answer (score 2):

I agree that enums is by far the safest and best solution to your problem.  Perhaps enums are not widely used in projects like Apache because enums are relatively new in Java (I think they came along in Java 1.5).

Comment: (New ? not really, Java 1.5 is from 2004)

Comment: "relatively" new.  I still run across a lot of Java APIs that were originally written before Java 1.5 and haven't taken the time/effort to switch over to using enums.  Ok, maybe me calling enums new shows my age a little.  I've been using Java since the 1.2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 valued logic, you are no longer talking about simple true/false conditions, you are talking about a state machine. Arguably state machines are among the most powerful paradigms in programming. If you aren't conversant with automata theory, look it up.